# How to get current locale in the controller

Tags: plugin-development, localization

I'm struggling to get current locale code from the controller, I would use craft.locale in the template, but craft()->locale does not do the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`craft.locale` from a template goes to the [`locale()`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/variables/CraftVariable.php#L86) method of the `CraftVariable` class, which just calls `craft()->language` from PHP, which you could use.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create a hidden input and set the value to `<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="{{ craft.locale }}">` and import that into the controller via `$locale = craft()->request->getPost('locale');` This will allow you to know the current selected locale in the CP.

Comment: A Very nice workaround, can't believe I didn't thought of that.